# Canvas draw image with TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript, canvas

```html
 <canvas id="vm" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
 
 <img id ="old" width="300" height="300" src="./img/vumeter.png">
```

I am trying to use the functionality of canvas draw Image in Typescript. 
I have picture of VU-Meter. I would like to draw a needle (level pointer) with values so that it can oscillate.

I could able to draw a needle which oscillates at the moment. But I wasn't able to draw the canvas element on the image. What am I doing wrong?

```js
export class LevelMeter {

  private readonly value: Array < number > ;
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, options: Options) {
    this.ctx = < CanvasRenderingContext2D > canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = './img/vumeter.png';
    this.img.onload = () => window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));

  }

  draw() {
    let _ctx = this.ctx;
    _ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    _ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    _ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    _ctx.save();
    _ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    _ctx.translate(150, 180);
    _ctx.rotate((Math.PI * ((Math.random() * 0.5) + 1.25))       _ctx.beginPath(); _ctx.moveTo(0, 0); _ctx.lineTo(160, 0);
      //_ctx.closePath();
      _ctx.stroke(); _ctx.restore();

      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));

    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see the image if you remove _ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500); ?

Comment: The way I understand it you first draw the image, then draw a white square over it (making it disappear) and last you draw the needle. I think you want to clear your canvas first using clearRect, then draw the image, then draw the needle. All of this for each frame

Comment: No i dont see the picture if i remove _ctx.fillRect

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: oh sorry..,yes I see the picture...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing a white square over your image with the fillRect call.

Each frame you start with a drawn canvas (the previous frame), you need to start clearing that one and then drawing the image on the empty canvas and last draw the needle over it:

```
export class LevelMeter {

  private readonly value: Array < number > ;
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, options: Options) {
    this.ctx = < CanvasRenderingContext2D > canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = './img/vumeter.png';
    this.img.onload = () => window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));

  }

  draw() {
    let _ctx = this.ctx;

    _ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    _ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    _ctx.save();
    _ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    _ctx.translate(150, 180);
    _ctx.rotate((Math.PI * ((Math.random() * 0.5) + 1.25))       
    _ctx.beginPath(); _ctx.moveTo(0, 0); _ctx.lineTo(160, 0);
      //_ctx.closePath();
      _ctx.stroke(); _ctx.restore();

      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));

    }
  }
```